# "(#135000) Generic user error" WhatsApp business api

Tags: whatsapp, whatsapi, whatsapp-cloud-api

I have created dynamic templates in whatsapp , but those are not working. Those is to work before but suddenly they have stopped working, below is the error that graph api is throwing.

```
{
"error": {
    "message": "(#135000) Generic user error",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 135000,
    "error_data": {
        "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
        "details": "Generic user error"
    },
    "fbtrace_id": "Ace-8VqShF4hwIg6IxODwwf"
}}
```

Comment: did you get this resolved?